# Lentidão em obter resposta da api usando HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

Estou com um problema critico, quando envio uma solicitação para a API, sempre demora receber a resposta, eu estou usando o gcm também, sempre chega no momento que a solicitação é enviada.

Mas quando a função vai na API, já demora, já chegou a demora mais de 2 minutos.

O pior é que as vezes vem rápido e em outros casos não, o problema não é na internet, pelo que notei também não é no servidor, já que o client restfull retorna rápido o resultado. A função que estou usando no Android é essa.

```
public static String postHttp(String targetURL, String urlParameters)
{
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);


        //Send request
        OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        w.write(urlParameters);
        w.flush();
        w.close ();

        //Get Response
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        String erro = "Erro de conexao com servidor (Método POST) - " + e.getMessage();
       // UpMotoLog.reportException(erro);
        Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
        return null;

    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parece-me que o problema pode ser tudo menos dessa função... Acho que o problema é mesmo um dos que enumeraste acima.

Comment: Mano, mas fora do app no cliente rest o resultado é imediato, e a internet é 15 MB. Foi isso que me deixou confuso, não sei se tem mais alguma coisa no android que possa prejudicar essa conexão. Vlw!

Comment: Como experimentaste cliente rest no android? Não te esqueças que wireless e bem diferente de cabo.

Comment: Brother, eu tenho um tread aqui rodando uma asynctask a cada um segundo, eu comentei ela aqui para fazer o testes, e me parece que diminuiu a demora; O que você me sugere nesse caso?